# Como enviar un correo con información de múltiples colecciones

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nodemailer

¿Es posible enviar un correo trayendo variables de diferentes colecciones?, es decir, si tengo la colección `usuarios` pero al momento de enviar el correo quiero que se envíe con variables también de la colección `puesto` y de la colección `turno`, como podría consultar las otras colecciones para traer los datos?, cabe destacar que se mkodificaría sólo la de `usuarios` generando el evento `onUpdate` y de allí llevar el id para las otras colecciones y consultar, pero no tengo la menos idea si se pueda o como hacerlo, algúna ayuda?.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'correo@gmail.com',
        pass: 'password'
    }
});
exports.CreateAlertMail = functions.firestore.document("arma_letal/{id}").onCreate((snap, context) => {    
        
    // DATOS DE LA INSPECCION PARA ENVIAR EL CORREO
     const name =             snap.data().f1_inspeccion_realizada_por.f1_mip_session_nombre;
     const email_inspeccion = snap.data().f1_inspeccion_realizada_por.f1_mip_session_correo;        
     const nserie =           snap.data().f1_nserie;

     const empresa_cliente =   snap.data().f1_empresa_cliente;
     const empresa_sede =      snap.data().f1_empresa_sede;
     const empresa_direccion = snap.data().f1_direccion_puesto;
     const fecha_inspeccion =  snap.data().f1_fecha_registro_arma_letal;

     const email_admin = snap.data().f1_registrado_por.f1_correo_Administrador;
     const email_coor =  snap.data().f1_registrado_por.f1_correo_Coordinador;
     const email_dro =   snap.data().f1_registrado_por.f1_correo_Dro;
    
    if(snap.data().f1_resultado_inspeccion_arma_letal === 'No apta para uso'){
        const alerta = snap.data().f1_resultado_inspeccion_arma_letal;
        return sendAlertEmail(name, email_inspeccion, nserie, empresa_cliente, empresa_sede, empresa_direccion, fecha_inspeccion, email_admin, email_coor, email_dro, alerta);
    } else if(snap.data().f1_resultado_inspeccion_arma_letal === 'Apta con control específico'){
        const alerta = snap.data().f1_resultado_inspeccion_arma_letal;
        return sendWarningEmail(name, email_inspeccion, nserie, empresa_cliente, empresa_sede, empresa_direccion, fecha_inspeccion, email_admin, email_coor, email_dro, alerta);
    } else{
        return null
    }
    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar firebase-admin para hacer esto, primero importas la librería y hacer referencia a la base de datos (en la parte de arriba después de **const nodemaile = requ...** ):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
```

Después ya en la función (dentro de **exports.CreateAlertMail = functions.firestore.docu...**) hacer un llamado normalmente:

```
db.collection('Colleccion').doc('Documento').then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log("Error leyendo documento de documento");
    } else {
        // Aquí puedes leer los documentos 
    }
})
```

Tal vez requieras hacer un Promise.all para poder leer todo antes de enviar el correo, o anidar las consultas.  Espero funcione. Saludos.

La consulta anidada quedaría algo así:

```
db.collection('Colleccion').doc('Documento').then(doc1 => {
    if (!doc1.exists) {
        console.log("Error leyendo documento de documento");
    } else {

        // Consulta 2
        db.collection('Colleccion2').doc('Documento2').then(doc2 => {
                if (!doc2.exists) {
                    console.log("Error leyendo documento de documento");
                } else {

                    // Consulta 3
                    db.collection('Colleccion3').doc('Documento3').then(doc3 => {
                            if (!doc3.exists) {
                                console.log("Error leyendo documento de documento");
                            } else {
                                // Aquí envias el mail

                                let datos1 = doc1.data()
                                let datos2 = doc2.data()
                                let datos3 = doc3.data()

                            }
                        })


                }
            })
    }
})
```

Comment: Sí creo que lo correcto es que se lea todo antes de poder enviar el correo, así no queda ninguna variable indefinida, sabes, como podría hacerlo para que se ejecute una vez todas las consultas hayan sido terminadas correctamente?

Comment: Creo que lo mas fácil es que anides las consultas como que dentro del callback de la primer consulta pongas la segunda, y en el callback de la segunda pones la tercera y en el ultimo call back ya envías el mail  Así aseguras que no esta indefinido nada.

Comment: Agregue un ejemplo de la consulta anidada